# How to use JSTL var in Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jstl

I am using following Jquery selector

```
$("#selectedQuery td input:radio").attr('checked', true);
```

Where `selectedQuery` is a JSTL variable declared as

```
<c:set var="selectedQuery" value="${dataRequestForm.queryMasterId}" />
```

I tested the selector with hard coded values and it's working fine but no luck when used with `selectedQuery`.
How can we use JSTL `<c:set>` var in Jquery ? Is there any work around ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a JSP:

```
<c:set var="selectedQuery" value="${dataRequestForm.queryMasterId}" />  

<script>
    $("#${selectedQuery} td input:radio").attr('checked', true);
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry for being late.I was offline for last 2 days. Here is generated script `$("#270 td input:radio").attr('checked', true);`. `270` is the `selectedQuery`.

Comment: There was a problem with jquery datatable. Your solution worked like a charm :) Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Mixing JSTL code in with the JavaScript can cause your code to become really jumbled. If it's unavoidable, I have all my JSTL variables set to JavaScript variables in one place:

```
<c:set var="selectedQuery" value="${dataRequestForm.queryMasterId}" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    //NOTE: we are sure 'selectedQuery' does not contain any double-quotes,
    // but most values will need to be escaped before doing this.
    var selectedQuery = "${selectedQuery}";

    // etc.
</script>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#" + selectedQuery + " td input:radio").attr('checked', true);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Will definately try to avoid it :)

Answer (score 2):

I do stuff like that all the time.  The JSP parser doesn't know or care about the difference between the contents of a `<script>` tag (whether using jQuery or not) and any other content in the JSP page.

It should work fine if you do:

```
<c:set var="selectedQuery" value="${dataRequestForm.queryMasterId}" />

...

<script>
    $("#${selectedQuery} td input:radio").attr('checked', true);
</script>
```

Note that this requires that the `<script>` element with your jQuery selector be inside of the same page/JSP scope as your `<c:set>`.  If they aren't in the same scope then of course this will not work.