# Syntax error occured when retrieveing JSTL variables from JQuery

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl

I want to use JSP variables in my JQuery. Please guide me how to figure it out..

Here is my code in JSP..

```
<c:set var="fontClass" value="unicode ieUnicode" />
```

And in my JS file , I simply retrieve and out put by JQuery . As like ..

```
     (1). var fontClass = '${fontClass}';
          console.log("Result values are--- "+fontClass);
     (2). console.log("Result values are--- "+$('fontClass');
```

But , these two things can not be satisfied my problems.
And I fond an article from [How to use JSTL var in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121905/how-to-use-jstl-var-in-jquery-selector). So , I tried with like that...

**JSP ::**

```
<c:set var="fontClass" value="unicode ieUnicode" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  var fontClass = "${fontClass}";
</script>
```

**JS File::**

```
var fontClass = '${fontClass}';
alert($("#${fontClass}"));
```

But I got ***Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #${fontClass}***

What wrong with my codes or any Suggestion ? Thanks in advance..

Comment: I am a newbie in JQuery.. So , I have many troubles in it . Please guide to me.

Comment: My syntax error is shown in firebug console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the JSTL `<c:set/>` value in your JS file like this. 
Your JSP is processed at server side and your JS at client side.

### To use the value in a JS file :

**JSP file**:

```
<c:set var="fontClass" value="unicode ieUnicode" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    yourJsFunction("${fontClass}");
</script>
```

**JS file**:

```
function yourJsFunction(fontClass) {
    // finalResult is a local variable
    var finalResult = fontClass;

}
```

### To use the value in inline javascipt code (not so good) :

**JSP file**:

```
<c:set var="fontClass" value="unicode ieUnicode" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    // finalResult is a global variable
    var finalResult = "${fontClass}";
</script>
```

**/!\** This is not a very good practice because this global variable has a common name and will be accessible from mostly anywhere. Have a look at the next solution :

### To use the value in inline javascipt code (better way using namespace) :

**JSP file**:

```
<!-- Define your namespace, which is a global object -->
<script>
    var yourCompany = yourCompany || {};
</script>

<c:set var="fontClass" value="unicode ieUnicode" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Set all values you want to your namespace
    yourCompany.fontClass = "${fontClass}";
    yourJsFunction();
</script>
```

**JS file**:

```
function yourJsFunction() {
    // The font class value set in your namespace is accessible like that :
    yourCompany.fontClass;
}
```

Comment: No problem, mine are coming ;)

Comment: @ LPO , by the way .. I don't want to show with alert. I want to save it in another variable . eg: var finalResult = "${fontClass}". How to do ? pls guide me patiently. I appreciated your answers.

Comment: @Cataclysm I edited my answer and add some explanations. Hope it is clear enough